# Optimistic lock failure when @Version is null

Tags: java, spring-data, optimistic-locking

I am working on some code to generate serial numbers. I will read and update a record in the database which holds the next number to generate. As I expect to have different threads accessing this record I just added the @Version label to a Timestamp field of the same entity and then control the OptimisticLockExceptions that could rise.

Also I would have several records like these in my database holding different serial numbers, they can be created or deleted depending on the business.

The domain object looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Preferences")
public class Preferences implements Serializable, DomainObject {
...
...
@Column(name="nextSerial")
private String nextSerial;

@Version
@Column(name="RefreshDate")
private Timestamp refreshDate;
...
```

Until here everything works fine, the problem comes when another application that shares the same data creates a Preferences record. When this application was built, the @Version column didn't exist so it will create the record with a Null value as refreshDate.

I am aware of this and I try to set a refreshDate and update the record, also tried to delete and create again the record but in any case, I will get an Exception like the next:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException:
>   Exception [EclipseLink-5001] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException Exception
>   Description: An attempt was made to delete the object
>   [com.core.domain.Preferences@5e092f04], but it has no version
>   number in the identity map.

So my question is, how can I handle this problem from my application?. Using triggers in the database to ensure a non null @Version is not desirable, also changing the other application isn't desirable either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you set a default value for refreshDate at creation time using DB means? Like

VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 -- for a numeric version

RefreshDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now() - for your case

Comment: Thanks dimirsen! I already did this and is working perfect. Still I was curious if  there existed any way to handle this at Java level.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with spring-data-mongo - and I solved it by implementing Persistable interface by entity class the following way:

```java
public class MyEntity extends Persistable<String> {
    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return get_id();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNull(getId());
    }
}
```

For me it helped - on updating existing document a version field just started to appear having 0 value. The trick is that by default [Spring uses @Version-annotated field (if it is present in entity) to define entity state](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/reference/is-new-state-detection.html). And by overriding isNew() we force Spring to use @Id field instead, while the  optimistic locking mechanism itself continues to work as usual.

I suppose, it should help for JPA as well